# Glassfish admin loading forever

Tags: java, glassfish

i have downloaded the .sh bundle of `Glassfish 3.1.2` on my mac machine and started the server using `./asadmin stat-domain`and tried to hit the url `http://localhost:4848/`

but the page is loading forever, i try `refreshing` the page too but no luck

here is my java configuration on my mac machine

```
java version "1.6.0_22"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03-307, mixed mode)
```

i have set my `JAVA_HOME` too before i have installed `glassfish`

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

following is the `server.log` i dont know what i am missing here

```
[#|2013-04-20T23:12:22.137+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.<init>(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1094)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.configurePipeline(XML11Configuration.java:1149)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.configurePipeline(XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.java:151)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:778)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:306)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:631)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:373)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:243)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:252)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:213)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:827)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:769)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: Schema factory class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl does not extend from SchemaDVFactory.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:71)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:52)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SchemaGrammar$BuiltinSchemaGrammar.<init>(SchemaGrammar.java:158)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SchemaGrammar.<clinit>(SchemaGrammar.java:904)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, payara **4.**(something) -- I tracked it down to file that was bundled in the modules directory - it contained a xerces implementation --

If you run the follwing command:

```
find <payara-dir> -name '*.jar' -exec grep -Hls SchemaDVFactory {} \;
```

you will find a jar file containing that class. Problem is rt.jar also contains an implementation.
I found this one

> ../glassfish/modules/aixporting-repackaged.jar

on my system

**tldr**
I think you may have downladed an aix version of payara that contains a bundled xerces implementation.

**solution**
download the correct (non-aix) version of payara

Comment: Where do you find the non aix version of Payara?

Comment: Found it under https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:fish.payara.distributions%20AND%20a:payara&core=gav 
With one of those distributions the admin console works again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable all network connections on your mac and then retry to surf to `http://localhost:4848/`? This could indicate problems with the JVM. (Too low rep to comment)

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using?  I've had no end of problems with glassfhish's admin console "not loading" on the mac version of safari and chrome.  It loaded fine in firefox, though.   Also, depending on instructions did you enable secure-admin?  If you did it'd be https, not http.

Comment: i have tried it on all the browsers but the result is same , can u tell me that how would i make `secure-admin` enable

Comment: `asadmin change-admin-password` and then
`asadmin enable-secure-admin` then connect with https

Comment: Also, try downloading the Oracle JDK and using it as JAVA_HOME instead. [Download Oracle Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Comment: Another thing, do a `netstat -an|grep 4848` and see if it's even listening?

Comment: but does `Oracle JDK 7 work on 10.6.8` ?